# new JSP in a parent window closing a popup child JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I am learning Apache Struts, JSP and building a simple web application. Now, I would like to see the feasibility of the below functionality.

Clicking a button on parent JSP page, a popup (also a JSP page) opens in a new window. I have a submit button in the popup JSP page.

When the user clicks on the submit button on the child popup JSP page, the child window closes and a new JSP page to be loaded on the parent window.

Is it possible to load a new JSP page in the parent window by closing the child JSP page. Or can I adopt reloading the page with different table in the same parent window.

Thanks, 
Kaygee

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by executing the following piece of JS on click or submit of the button/form in the popup window.

```
window.opener.location = newURL;
```

The [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) refers to the parent window.

Comment: @Kaygee if the answer has worked for you, mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)